# counting tasks between a timeframe

Tags: excel, time, count

Im looking to count how many times something appears on my list between a certain timeframe, this will cross over midnight

I am trying to find the outcome of how many times the "From" is counted on the list between 18:00 and 06:00 to capture the team productivity

I tried this, but it does not capture the "From" just how many tasks there was

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&K3,A:A,"<="&K4)+COUNTIFS(G:G,"COMCS"&K3,G:G,"COMCS"&K4)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does something like this help? `=LET(a,R4C5:R28C5,b,FILTER(a,a>=DATE(2023,11,10)),ROWS(FILTER(b,b<DATE(2023,12,10))))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula (in `B26`):

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[From],$A26,Table1[Date],">="&B$23,Table1[Date],"<"&B$24)
```

I have used my own notation, because yours was not clear.
[image: Counting]